# What was the intention of the speaker when she said with a rising tone in the below audio?

Tags: intonation

When the sentence [**I went to the theatre last night**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXkns_DkYDCna_LqOcam0ReWI2z3XWJ1/view?usp=sharing) was said with a **rising intonation** at the end,...

> What was the speaker trying to convey or What kinds of situation could she
>   use that type of rising intonation?

Comment: Honestly, I don't feel there is a "rising intonation" as the only thing she says is "I went to the theater last night". I don't think its possible to judge someone's tone from just those words. It could be her normal way of speaking, we can't know that for sure as there is no other speech from her to compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rising tone occurs in particular British dialects (RP, etc) and settings. The speaker is signalling that the conversation should or is expected to continue by her talking about her experience at the theater after a second utterance.

The man's "Did you?" is not intended as a literal question about if she actually did or not, but an acknowledgement that the speaker should go ahead and continue with her story or information about her theater visit.